# Ghostdoc-like plugin for IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, automation, javadoc, ghostdoc

I've become lazy in my old age. For my C# work I've become quite reliant on Roland Weigelt's excellent [GhostDoc](http://www.roland-weigelt.de/ghostdoc/) plugin for Visual Studio.

Is anyone aware of a similar plugin for Java work in IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 2):

The builtin javadoc completion does some of this - if you type /** and press  it puts parameters and return types into a skeleton javadoc.

Not quite the same as Ghostdoc, but -q on the method name brings up its javadoc with a link to the relevant super type docs, if applicable.

I presume you have looked in the [plugin repository](http://plugins.intellij.net/).